# How to find out if user is active with winapi

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a small windows program and I want it to only run when the windows user is active. As soon as the user is inactive (for example no more mouse/keyboard events) I want to make my program go to sleep and wait until the user is back to the keyboard.
The program I use is working minimized in the tray only. I want it to work like an inverse screensaver. As soon as the user is away for X minuites, I want it to stop and run again as soon as the user is back.

So how do I get the informations or events when my window is minimized or the mouse is moved outside of my window? Maybe some trick of how screensavers do it is also helpfull?

Comment: Have a look at [`GetLastInputInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) for one useful function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was what I was looking for! Too bad you didn't reply that as an answer, so I couldn't mark your post as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Roger Rowland solved my Question!